# Mathematica doesn't simplify 1.` x

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics, polynomials, algebra

I'm debugging a program that uses polynomials with numerical coefficients and it turns out that mathematica does not simplify `` 1.` x[1]^2 x[2]^2 `` to `x[1]^2 x[2]^2`. This causes bad behaviour, even for built-in functions:

```
FactorList[ 1.` x[1]^2 x[2]^2 ]
(* {{1., 1}, {x[1], 2}, {1. x[2]^2, 1}} *)
```

When I evaluate
`` 1.` x[1]^2 x[2]^2 == x[1]^2 x[2]^2 `` nothing happens but `` Simplify[1.` x[1]^2 x[2]^2 == x[1]^2 x[2]^2] `` does return `True` though.

I can see that it might not want to treat a term with a numerical coefficient as equal to a purely symbolic one but the behaviour of `FactorList` doesn't seem like intended behaviour. I can't just add a `Simplify` everywhere and using replacement rules of the form `1. *x_->x` looks ridiculous in the code...

**Question:** Can people replicate this behaviour and if so: is there a way to fix this problem without the use of `Simplify` or ad-hoc replacement rules?

Comment: `Rationalize` is an easy way to convert `1.` to `1`, which will then makes it disappear from multiplications.

Comment: It works if there are no symbols involved. For example `1. ==1` gives `True`. But `1. *x==1*x` gives back the input and not `True`.  So you'd have to use `Simplify`

Comment: `expr /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x]` ? Not generally applicable but it can be modified further.

Comment: @Syed I think `Simplify` is simpler :)

Comment: `Simplify[1.]` vs `Simplify[1.] /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x]` . I think the question is why should Mma simplify `1.` in the first place?

Comment: @Syed  help for `==` says `2==2. gives True.`  because it says before it `Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)`

Comment: Investigate `OneIdentity`.